# How can I return this 2d array?

Tags: c++, arrays

How can I properly return a 2d array from a function? When I cout the values to test, it works, but when I try to return it, the compiler gives me an error saying that the function types do not match.

What is the correct way to prototype a function that will return a 2d array??

> int** arytest(int*, int); // prototype

Here is what I have...

```
    // an ampty array
    int array2d[2][10];

    // pointers to parts
    int *array1 = array2d[0];
    int *array2 = array2d[1];

    // fill "arrays"
    for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        array1[i] = uncommons[i];
    }
    for (i = 0; i<10; ++i) {
        array2[i] = totals[i];
    }
    for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        if (array2d[0][i] == 1)
            cout << i << " occurs " << array2d[1][i]; // testing

    }

    return array2d;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use `std::vector` instead of C-style arrays?

Comment: I am new to C++ and haven't gotten that far yet into the language. Is there a way to do this without the use of vectors?

Comment: You have to use dynamic allocation with `new`. Local arrays can't be returned.

Comment: `std::vector` _is_ the __very__ basics of C++. Far more basic than manually allocating arrays with `new`.

Comment: An `int[2][0]` is not the same as an `int**`.